# Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'=show with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using NetBeans IDE, rails 4, ruby 2.2.0. I am trying to use ajax to display the 'show' page but, instead, get the Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'=show error. In format.html I am using an 'id' property to set the transaction value, how do I do that in ajax?

```
  format.html { render :action => 'show',:id=>@transaction } --- id is set
  format.js {render :js => "window.location = '/transactions/show'"}  --
  -   how do I set an 'id' property in js?
```

Thank you.

Comment: What path are you getting this error on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should, within what you have above, just require the following edit:

```
format.js {render :js => "window.location = '/transactions/#{@transaction.id}'"} 
# the above should render something like '/transactions/12345' as the URI/URL
```

In short, `/transactions/show` is not a valid URI for a standard Rails show page. In a terminal window, run `rake routes` and you will see something more like the following for the transactions, and all other, routes:

```
transactions GET /transactions/:id(.:format) transactions#show
```

So ... the :id in the route description, above, needs to be an actual ID of the saved object/instance and not the string 'show' when you create a link. This way, the Rails router knows what to do with the request (i.e., what controller to call, what data to pass in, etc.).

Comment: if the path for transactions ever changes (not that it would under normal circumstances), this would cause problems down the road... you're absolutely right in your answer, however, the solution is a little brittle by not using the path helper for the route.

Comment: I agree ... I went with an answer more directly related to her question but, again, totally agree that the helper is a more ideal approach.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your route for a transaction is defined following rails conventions, you would simply do the following:

```
"window.location='#{transaction_path(@transaction)}'"
```

If that doesn't do the trick, please add the contents of your `routes.rb` file so we can answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
format.js {render :js => "window.location = '/transactions/show'"}
```

Do:

```
format.js {render :js => "window.location = #{transactions_path(@transaction)}"}
```

Here `transactions_path(@transaction)` will be evaluated to relative path for transaction's show page. Issue is in `/transactions/show` which is mapped to `'/transactions/:id` in your routes.rb. And in `TransactionsController#show` the code is trying to find a transaction with an id `show`, hence the error.